# Changing states without reloading previous view data when I go back to it

Tags: angularjs, meanjs, swig-template

I am new to angular and was wondering if I could somehow change states (after clicking on link from a list of search results) and load a new view, hide the old one (including header !), but not unload it/not have to request JSON data again if I got back to the search results for products view from the product details view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this will be a really short answer.
Take a look at this:

[$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) You can play around with it so you won't need to reload pages when going back and forth.